# datagridviewLinkColumn - displayed text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

`tableadapter` fills my `datagridview` with data, 2 of the cols are relative paths to files.

When I set `datagridview.useColumnTextForLinkValue = false`, it displays the relative path stored in the db. If there is not a rel. path for the record, the cell is blank, this is OK.

When I set `datagridview.useColumnTextForLinkValue = true`, then set `datagridview.text = "click here"` every record for this column is populated with `"click here"` regardless of whether a relative path actually exists in the db. So, it's misleading.

Any workarounds??

Comment: First I guess when you write DatagridView you mean DataGridViewLinkColumn. From Msdn,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn.aspx this is how it works. What are you trying to do?

Comment: 2 of the cols in my datagridview are datagridviewlinkColumn, the rest are datagridviewTextBoxColumn. my question pertains to the 2 datagridviewLink columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to display some text when the value is null. You are wrong using these properties because it apply to the entire column (null value and others).

Try to hook the [Datagridview.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event and Check for null values.

```
Private Sub dgv_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)_
    Handles dataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If Me.dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Mycolumn" Then 
        If e.Value Is Nothing OrElse e.value Is DbNull.Value Then
            e.Value = "Click here"          
            e.FormattingApplied = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```